# Can this flash be triggered by my coolpix s7000 integrated flash

Tags: flash

It says wireless trigger sensor but i'm sure my little s7000 doesn't have that, so can it be triggered by the s7000 flash ?

http://www.ebay.ca/itm/Speedlite-Digital-Slave-Flash-for-Canon-DSLR-T6i-T5i-T4i-T3i-by-Altura-Photo-/201689346901?hash=item2ef59f3355:g:x20AAOSwpLNX9xzM

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your little s7000 flash can trigger it, but only in *optical slave* mode. That means the off camera flash will sense when the camera's flash fires and will fire as well.

You'll have to select all settings (power level, zoom head, etc.) on the flash itself ahead of time because all the flash from the camera will do is cause it to "fire".

You may or may not have issues with pre-flash,lag and shutter sync. If your s7000's flash fires a preflash before it takes the picture try using S2 mode on the altura flash to keep it from firing too soon based on the preflash. If that doesn't work then turn off red eye reduction and any other option that uses a preflash to limit the camera's flash to firing only when the shutter is open and use S1 slave mode on the external flash.

If you can control the shutter speed of the s7000 try using a shutter time longer/slower than about 1/30 second and gradually shortening the shutter time until you find the point at which the entire frame is not illuminated by the external flash when it fires.

The relatively weak power of the s7000's built-in flash will also limit the distance and direction at which you can place the external flash. The rotating head of the external flash will allow you to rotate the sensor under the flash head to keep it pointed towards your s7000 and that should help somewhat.